# How to sort two-dimensional array of ranges in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, range

I have two-dimensional array of ranges `(Range<String.Index>)`

```
var arrayToSort = [
                   [14..<20, 10..<29, 13..<21],
                   [7..<11, 1..<5, 4..<8], 
                   [30..<50, 40..<54, 32..<60]
                  ]
```

and I need sort it in ascending order of start.Index of the first ranges from each element of the two-dimensional array, to have the array like this

```
 var sortedArray = [
                   [7..<11, 1..<5, 4..<8],
                   [14..<20, 10..<29, 13..<21],
                   [30..<50, 40..<54, 32..<60]
                  ]
```

Comment: Why are they in quotes?

Comment: You claim to have a 2-d array of `Range<String.Index>`, but accepted an answer working with a 2-d array of `String`. For future readers it would be helpful to clarify what you are actually doing.

Comment: @Martin R It was my mistake to put first the strings instead of ranges (I corrected), Oleg Gordiichuk have seen this first probably. With ranges it is the same right idea to use comparison of $0[0]  and $1[0] as he suggested - $0[0].startIndex and $1[0].startIndex(I have tested it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort according to the start index of the first range in each array
element, call `sort()` with a closure that compares the start index
of the first range of its two parameters:

```
let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort {
    $0.first?.startIndex < $1.first?.startIndex
}
```

The optional chaining with `?` takes care of the case that a nested
array is empty. In that case `$n.first?.startIndex` evaluates to `nil`
(and the corresponding element is sorted before all others).

Full self-contained example:

```
let s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let arrayToSort = [
    [ s.rangeOfString("EFG")!, s.rangeOfString("MNO")!],
    [ s.rangeOfString("DEFGH")!, s.rangeOfString("XYZ")!],
    [ ]
]
print(arrayToSort)
// [[Range(4..<7), Range(12..<15)], [Range(3..<8), Range(23..<26)], []]

let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort {
    $0.first?.startIndex < $1.first?.startIndex
}
print(sortedArray)
// [[], [Range(3..<8), Range(23..<26)], [Range(4..<7), Range(12..<15)]]
```

**Update for Swift 4 and later:**

```
let s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let arrayToSort = [
    [ s.range(of: "EFG")!, s.range(of: "MNO")!],
    [ s.range(of: "DEFGH")!, s.range(of: "XYZ")!],
    [ ]
]

let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sorted(by: {
    $0.first?.lowerBound ?? s.startIndex < $1.first?.lowerBound ?? s.startIndex
})
```

Comment: Nice answer. But it is impossible to get result that user expect by this approach.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk What's your basis for saying that it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @KennethBruno run this sorting for the input array and see output

Comment: I did and got this result, which seems correct: `[[Range(7..<11), Range(1..<5), Range(4..<8)], [Range(14..<20), Range(10..<29), Range(13..<21)], [Range(30..<50), Range(40..<54), Range(32..<60)]]`

Answer (score 0):

For solving of the issue use functional programing that is introduced in swift :

```
   var arrayToSort = [
        ["14..<20", "10..<29", "13..<21"],
        ["7..<11", "1..<5", "4..<8"],
        ["30..<50", "40..<54", "32..<60"]
    ]

let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort { (NSMaxRange(NSRangeFromString($0[0]))) < (NSMaxRange(NSRangeFromString($1[0]))) }
```

Fixing with location of the NSRange

```
let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort { ((NSRangeFromString($0[0]).location)) < ((NSRangeFromString($1[0]).location)) }
```

Comment: This sorts on the end index, not on the start index as required in the question.

Comment: @MartinR i create NSRange from Range<String.Index> and than take max. Could you please explain where i am woking with string

Comment: ... and that gives the end index of the range. Check the result if you replace `"7..<11"` by `"7..<99"`. (But I did not vote on your answer :)

Comment: `"14..<20"` is a *string*, not a Range<String.Index>.

Comment: Interesting why someone put -1 and do not add any comment